# Why is my UDPClient null once in a while

Tags: c#, exception, network-programming, udp

Can someone explain to me why this code fails once in a while with a null exception for udpLink while sending?

```
            udpLink = new UdpClient(ipAddress, 514);
            using (udpLink)
            {
                  udpLink.Send(rawMsg, rawMsg.Length);
            }
```

This is the new code on how I fixed it.

```
            udpLink = new UdpClient(ipAddress, 514);
            using (udpLink)
            {
                  if (udpLink != null) udpLink.Send(rawMsg, rawMsg.Length);
            }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is that udp variable in your code? Did you mean to pass udpLink to the using statement?

Comment: Martin, ah...sorry just a typo when asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it really is the problem, but I guess it's the way how you use the using statement. I would do it like this:

```
using (UdpClient udpLink = new UdpClient(ipAddress, 514))
{
    udpLink.Send(rawMsg, rawMsg.Length);
}
```

Comment: Functionally, that's the same, all you did was remove a line of code.

Comment: I'm not sure why this worked, but it did.  I've been running the code for sometime now with not even one exception after I made your suggested code change.  

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether or not this code segment is in a loop that executes thousands of times you might be maxing out on connections (speaking from experience).  you can do a netstat -an and if it scrolls for more than a second chances are that could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you should be getting a null pointer exception on udpLink.  You are sure its udpLink that is null and not rawMsg?  Also, you're sure you are throwing a NullPointerException and not a SocketException or other exception?